# How to calculate complexity of such loop

Tags: time-complexity

What is time complexity of such loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   for(int j = i + 1; j < arrray.length; j++){
   // Some O(1) operation
   }
}
```

Comment: The answer would be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Two nested loops `O(n^2)`

The time complexity of a nested loop is equal to the number of times the innermost statement is executed.

More info on time complexity and a fun read refer to:

https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/time-complexity-analysis-of-loop-in-programming